# What's the second-best way to make a skinnable user interface component?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, skinning

I've been asked to make one of the components, which mimics a real-world appliance, in our application have a custom appearance, which varies depending on the make of the appliance being mimicked, so I need to make it skinnable.

Now, I'm aware that the best way to do custom appearances in user interfaces, is not to do that at all; but I don't think I'll be able to get that past management, so...

What's the the second-best way to make a skinnable user interface component?  Our app is winforms-based so I was wondering whether it makes sense to use a `WebBrowser` control, write the skins in HTML, and somehow hook the DOM elements up to our app's events.  Should I do it that way, or is there a simpler (and free) way of doing it?

Answer (score 6):

I would use WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) or a skinnable component library like DevExpress (let's you design your own skins).

[DevExpress Skin Creation Tutorial](http://tv.devexpress.com/CustomSkins.movie)

Comment: I'd agree that WPF ought to be the way to go.

Comment: I'm afraid ours is a winforms app, not WPF, but I'll have a look at DevExpress - thanks.

Comment: Changing a non-skinnable UI to a skinnable one is almost certainly a complete rewrite, so the fact that your existing app is Winforms shouldn't hold you back from using WPF.